# How to solve "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" at runtime?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

There is a problem at runtime with this code which is :

> ```
> java.lang.classNotFoundException: oracle:jdbc:driver:OracleDriver
> ```

but another program of same JDBC driver are run properly but this JDBC driver is found a exception in java applet. So please help me for this problem.

*I'm new in Java.*

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

/*<applet code="EmpDetails" width=300 height=500></applet>*/

public class EmpDetails extends Applet implements ActionListener{
TextField firstName, lastName, userId, pass, email, phone;
Button submit,cancel;
String msg = "";

public void init(){

    setLayout(new GridLayout(10,2,0,30));


    Label fname = new Label("First Name : ");
    Label lname = new Label("\nLast Name : ");
    Label uid = new Label("User Id : ");
    Label pas = new Label("Password : ");
    Label emailid = new Label("Email Id : ");
    Label ph = new Label("Phone : ");

    firstName = new TextField(10);
    lastName = new TextField(10);
    userId = new TextField(16);
    pass = new TextField(16);
    email = new TextField(30);
    phone = new TextField(12);
    pass.setEchoChar('*');

    submit = new Button("Submit");
    cancel = new Button("Cancel");

    add(fname);
    add(firstName);

    add(lname);
    add(lastName);
    add(uid);
    add(userId);
    add(pas);
    add(pass);
    add(emailid);
    add(email);
    add(ph);
    add(phone);
    add(submit);
    add(cancel);

    firstName.addActionListener(this);
    lastName.addActionListener(this);
    userId.addActionListener(this);
    pass.addActionListener(this);
    email.addActionListener(this);
    phone.addActionListener(this);
    submit.addActionListener(this);
    cancel.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        String str = ae.getActionCommand();
        if(str.equals("Submit"))
        {
                try{
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
                    String id = "system";
                    String passw = "root";

                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url , id , passw);

                    Statement st = con.createStatement();

                    String u,fn,ln,ps,em,pn;
                    u = userId.getText();
                    fn = firstName.getText();
                    ln = lastName.getText();
                    ps = pass.getText();
                    em = email.getText();
                    pn = phone.getText();
                    String urld = "INSERT INTO EMPDETAILS(id,firstname,lastname,email,password,phone)" + "values" + "('" + u + "','" + fn + "','" + ln + "','" + em + "','" + ps + "','" + pn + "')";
                    st.executeUpdate(urld);
                    con.close();
                    st.close();
                    msg = "Recode added successfull ";
                }

                catch(Exception e){ msg = e.toString();}
        }

        else{
            msg = "No any data added";

        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString(msg,6,300);


    }
}
```

Comment: The exception comes from when you try `Class.forName("....OracleDriver")` because you don't have the Oracle JDBC classes on your classpath.  There are many, many other questions exactly like this, a quick google search will get you an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why you encounter this Exception is, that you use the wrong package to refer to the `OracleDriver` class

Therefore, you should change the incorrect class load call

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

into

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

as this class file implements the `java.sql.Driver` interface which is actually checked for at runtime.

For reference, see also the description in the [official JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) provided by Oracle:

> The Oracle JDBC driver class that implements the java.sql.Driver interface.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

- 1) Firstly download `ojdbc6.jar` and `ojdbc6_g.jar` from google.
- 2) If you are connecting to Oracle 11g from Java and running on version Java 6 then include `ojdbc6.jar` or `ojdbc6_g.jar` in your application's classpath.
- 3) Once you complete the download, paste the files in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\ext folder`.

Comment: **How** does one do the step you say which is to "include ojdbc6.jar in your application's classpath"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a reference solution for those who has Java 1.8 and oracle Version 12+. In my case i had Java 1.8 therefore downloading oracle8.jar and placing that in the classpath as mentioned above helped to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean "placing that in the classpath"? We are trying to solve this same error in Python and the meaning of that statement is unclear.

Comment: As i mentioned you need to download the oracle8.jar and then paste that jar in "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\lib\ext" path. This should solve your problem. It solved mine

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `startNetworkServer` within derby Folder (using cmd.exe). Typically, you will get port 1527; then in Eclipse -> Properties -> java path -> classpath you add .jar by browsing to `derby/lib/derbyclient.jar;` finally within java class with main() method you get

`connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/nameOfDataBase");`

Enjoy.