# Getting ClassNotFoundError for oracle and sybase db connection if ran the war, but in eclipse it is working fine

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, oracle, sybase

I have built an feature in application to test db connection. In local i'm able to test all three db sqlserver, sybase and oracle. but if create war file and run war in windows/linux server then getting above error for oracle and sybase. and if i remove oracle or sybase code and dependency then others are working fine.
I have checked in war file inside /web-inf/lib/ it has jtds, ojdbc8 and jconnect4 lib/dependency
oracle conn code

```
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
```

Sybase conn code

```
import com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SybaseConnectionManager {
    public static Connection getSybaseConnection(String serverName, String databaseName, String userName, String password, String url) throws DataGeneratorException {
        SybDataSource ds = new SybDataSource();

        try {
            ds.setServerName(serverName);
            ds.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
            ds.setUser(userName);
            ds.setPassword(password);

            // Splitting URL by semicolon
            String[] params = url.split(";");
            for (String param : params) {
                String[] props = param.split("=");
                switch (props[0].toUpperCase()) {
                    case "PORT":
                        ds.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(props[1]));
                        break;
                    case "ENCRYPT_PASSWORD":
                        ds.setENCRYPT_PASSWORD(props[1]);
                        break;
                    case "RETRY_WITH_NO_ENCRYPTION":
                        ds.setRETRY_WITH_NO_ENCRYPTION(props[1]);
                        break;
                    case "JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS":
                        ds.setJCE_PROVIDER_CLASS(props[1]);
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Get the connection
            Connection con = ds.getConnection();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            return con;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Handling Sybase Exception", e);
            throw new DataGeneratorException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

the below error is from when i'm testing oracle db connection

```
2023-09-13104:19:14,724Z (UTC+0) [http-nio-9091-exec-7] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[. [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/testapp] threw exception [handler dispatch failed; nested execption is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] with root cause
java.lang-ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.StackOverflowError [in thread "http-nio-9091-exec-1"]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
at org-springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
at java.base/java.lang.Classloader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassl(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Classloader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassloader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassloader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassloader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassloader.findClass(URLClassLoader •Java:451)
at java. base/ java lang ClassLoader. loadClass(ClassLoader. java: 588)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
at java.base/java.lang.Classloader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassloader.java:174)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassloader.java:555)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassloader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
at java.base/java.lang.Classloader.loadClass(ClassLoader. java:588)
at org-springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURlClassloader.java:151)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Classloader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassi(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassloader.defineClass(SecureClassloader.java:174)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassloader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
at java .base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
at iava.base/iava.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

when I'm Testing sybase conn as well it is saying same classnotfounderror, could not initialize class com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.sybdriver
and for oracle i'm using ojdbc8 and for sybase jconnect4
and 1 more strange thing if i remove code of sybase conn and dependency oracle is working fine and vice versa
both are not working together, getting conflict i guess, but not sure how to resolve it

Comment: In the stacktrace, the error says `could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`, notice the fully qualified class name. While, your code says `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`. So, there is package name difference. `oracle.jdbc` vs `oracle.jdbc.driver`.

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-vs-oracle-jdbc-oracledriver-7699 - `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is deprecated, use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead. So, try using `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");`. And are you sure ojdbcXX.jar is in classpath?

Comment: @Ishan Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); i tried with this as well but getting the same error

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Oracle_8i,_9i_&_10g - "For Oracle 9i onwards you should use oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver rather than oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver as Oracle have stated that oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is deprecated and support for this driver class will be discontinued in the next major release. "

Comment: Hmm.. Then are you sure a valid JAR file in classpath? Can you open it in some Zip tool and see if it is valid and it has `oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.class` file inside?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682483/how-to-solve-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver?rq=3   in this question as well they suggested same solution

Comment: @Ishan checked in eclipse it has OracleDriver.class, As it is working in my local eclipse ide. but when i create war and run in server then only getting error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255255/discussion-between-seriously-and-ishan).

Comment: JDK version is also the same on the server?  Could there be an older version of Java on the server, while the driver could be compiled with a newer version?

Answer (score 1):

Continued discussion over chat...

It seems the issue is there are 2 DB drivers being used simultaneously.
When `DriverManager.getConnection()` is called, it seems it does not get which driver has to be used.  Ideally it should.  The first parameter 'url' tells the `getConnection` method which driver should be used.
Still, if only one DB connectivity is checked, and only one driver is kept, it works. As soon as 2 drivers are added and both are tried to be checked it fails with one of the two drivers. This seems wrong. This should work fine. But still, it doesn't.

Ideally, the root cause of this should be found.  But if not, an alternative is to have small console applications. One for each DB.

```
java -cp ojdbc8.jar -jar oraclechecker.jar
```

and

```
java -cp sybase.jar -jar sybasechecker.jar
```

Those can be called and tested like this.  This will result in a separate JVM initialization - each with a different DB Driver and just ONE.

The main webapp can use

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java", "-cp", "ojdbc8.jar", "-jar", "oraclechecker.jar");
```

Commands like this to call those as external commands.
The Web-App itself won't need to have any DB driver.

This is just one of the possibilities...

Check the following issue:
[How to use multiple JDBC drivers in the same application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945289/how-to-use-multiple-jdbc-drivers-in-the-same-application)

It also says that 2 different DB drivers can work in parallel.  The first parameter `url` of `DriverManager.getConnection` will determine which driver to use.  E.g. `jdbc:mysql:` or `jdbc:oracle:thin:`

I also tried the same in local Tomcat 10. Created a `testdb.jsp`

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<html>
<body>
    <pre>
<%
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

    String[][] connDetails = { { "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()" },
            { "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:xxxxx/xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL" } };

    for (String[] cd : connDetails) {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(cd[0], cd[1], cd[2])) {
            out.println("Connected successfully to " + cd[0]);
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(cd[3]); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    out.println("\t" + rs.getTimestamp(1));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            out.println("Error: " + x);
        }
    }
%>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

```
D:\apache-tomcat-10.1.8\webapps\ROOT>tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume Data
Volume serial number is XXXXX
D:.
│   index.jsp
│   RELEASE-NOTES.txt
│   testdb.jsp
│
└───WEB-INF
    │   web.xml
    │
    └───lib
            mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar
            ojdbc11.jar
```

Started tomcat.  And calling http://localhost:8080/testdb.jsp results in:

```
Connected successfully to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    2023-09-14 12:28:51.0
Connected successfully to jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:xxxxx/xxxxx
    2023-09-14 12:29:08.360942
```

Comment: Yeah it works, I had to test conn to 3 db(sqlserver, oracle, sybase) only issue is both of them together(oracle and sybase). if i keep conn code and lib of two db(sqlserver, oracle) or (sqlserver, sybase) then i'm able to test conn in both these scenario, getting error only if i keep oracle and sybase together

Comment: Yeah, that is strange. As such any number of DBs should work OK. All the DBs will have different jdbc url prefix. So, `DriverManager.getConnection` should be able to determine which one to use. This is very strange.

Comment: @Seriously, Check this out - https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-integration-jdbc/issues/99 - a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you shared, The JDBC drivers are available in lib folder of war. In that case class loaders available in your code could not access the libraries folder inside the war. only the parallelwebapp class loader can access the lib folder inside the war. you can get more information by referring to tomcat class loader hierarchy in documentations(https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). you can do 2 things 1. you have to use correct parallel web app class loader in the thread you try to load the driver. 2. Move the oracle jdbc drivers to lower library level such as tomcat lib folder or to jvm level class path. This issue exist in some systems and not available in others is due to the level of parallellism of the system. (parallelism level is equal to number of physical threads-1)

Comment: If i keep 2 lib and conn code of (sqlserver and oracle) or (sqlserver and sybase) then it is working, it is conflicting when i keep oracle and sybase lib together in and run the war in linux server and test conn