# How to make Connection to sybase db not using jconnect4 in java

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, sybase, jconnect

I am successfullt able to connect to sybase db using jconnect4 lib & bcpkix-jdk15on and below code

```
import com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SybaseConnectionManager {
    public static Connection getSybaseConnection(String serverName, String databaseName, String userName, String password, String url) throws DataGeneratorException {
        SybDataSource ds = new SybDataSource();

        try {
            ds.setServerName(serverName);
            ds.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
            ds.setUser(userName);
            ds.setPassword(password);

            // Splitting URL by semicolon
            String[] params = url.split(";");
            for (String param : params) {
                String[] props = param.split("=");
                switch (props[0].toUpperCase()) {
                    case "PORT":
                        ds.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(props[1]));
                        break;
                    case "ENCRYPT_PASSWORD":
                        ds.setENCRYPT_PASSWORD(props[1]);
                        break;
                    case "RETRY_WITH_NO_ENCRYPTION":
                        ds.setRETRY_WITH_NO_ENCRYPTION(props[1]);
                        break;
                    case "JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS":
                        ds.setJCE_PROVIDER_CLASS(props[1]);
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Get the connection
            Connection con = ds.getConnection();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            return con;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Handling Sybase Exception", e);
            throw new DataGeneratorException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I tried connecting to sybase db using jtds lib but getting error "Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network". I created jdbc url for jtds like below

```
jdbc:jtds:sybase://<hostname>:<portno>/<dbname>
conn prop below:--
user:
password:
encrypt_password:
retry_with_no_encryyption:
jce_provider_class:
```

why I'm trying to connect with sybase because of this issue jconnect4 with ojdbcx lib giving noclassfounderror in linux server when used in single application.
[Getting ClassNotFoundError for oracle and sybase db connection in linux server, but in local wndows eclipse it is working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096194/getting-classnotfounderror-for-oracle-and-sybase-db-connection-in-linux-server)

Comment: If you Google for "sybase jdbc driver" you will see a number of search results.  The Sybase documentation suggests the SQL Anywhere JDBC 3.0 driver or the SQL Anywhere JDBC 4.0 driver or the jConnect driver.  There are a few options to try.